# Is there a Spark like Accumulator for Kafka Streams?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Spark has a useful API for accumulating data in a thread safe way https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.util.AccumulatorV2 and comes with some out-of-box useful accumulators e.g. for Longs https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.util.LongAccumulator

I usually use accumulators for wiring in debugging, profiling, monitoring and diagnostics into Spark jobs.  I usually fire off a Future before running a Spark job to periodically print the stats (e.g. TPS, histograms, counts, timings, etc)

So far I cannot find anything that is similar for Kafka Streams.  Does anything exist?  I imagine this is possible at least for each instance of a Kafka app, but to make this work across several instances would require creating an intermediate topic.

Comment: Requests to recommend / find tools or libraries are off topic here.

Comment: Kafka Streams has aggregators and reducers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka Streams avoids concurrency by design -- if the accumulated does not need to be fault-tolerant, you can do it in memory and flush it out via a wall-clock time punctuation.

If it needs to be fault-tolerant, you can use a state store and scan the whole store in a punctuation to flush it out.

This will give you task-level accumulation. Not sure how Spark's accumulator works in detail, but if it give you a "global" view, I assume that it needs the send data over network, and one single instance only has access to the data (or maybe a broadcast instead -- not sure, how consistency would be guaranteed for the broadcast case). Similar, you could send the data to a topic (with 1 partition) to collect all data globally into a single place.

Comment: > "Similar, you could send the data to a topic (with 1 partition) to collect all data globally into a single place."

This could work (though we'd have to manually create topic cos our cluster not got auto-create enabled). The topic would need to be aggregated when read right?  I can't see how this could be classed as concurrency, so don't see why this couldn't be wrapped in a nice API for Kafka Streams.

Comment: I don't say, it can't be wrapped with a nice API -- my answer targets what you would need to do with the current API. Feel free to file a feature request Jira :)